# Excluding templates from requirejs optimization

Tags: javascript, templates, requirejs, gruntjs

I have an application that uses underscore.js templates and loads them via require.js + text plugin:

```
define([..., 'text!templates/app/authentication.html'], function(..., Template) { 
... 
});
```

All works fine but now I am going to concatenate all my js files to one by means of Grunt.js and require.js optimizer. Here are the corresponding section in grunt file:

```
 requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            name : 'main',
            baseUrl: "www/js",
            optimize: "none",
            out: "www/js/result.js",
            stubModules : ['text'],
            paths : {
                text: 'vendor/text',
                ...
            },

            shim: {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But grunt throws me next error:

```
Running "requirejs:compile" (requirejs) task
>> Tracing dependencies for: nexusapp
>> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory
>> 'D:\templates\app\authentication.html'
>> In module tree:
>>     main
>>       app
>>         app.authentication
>>           text
Warning: RequireJS failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

The optimizer is trying to read file ignoring specified `baseUrl`.
How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know that to exclude a module from RequireJS compilation you would specify '**empty:**' for its path in the config file.  Like this:

```
{
    ...
    ...
    paths: {
            'module_you_want_1': '/path/to/module/you/want/1',
            'module_you_want_2': '/path/to/module/you/want/2',
            'module_you_dont_want': 'empty:'
        },
    ...
    ...
}
```